# Find URLs, @replies and #hashtags from Tweets

Tags: php, regex, text, twitter

I'm building a little Twitter thing in PHP and I'm trying to parse URLs, @replies and #hashtags and make them into clickable links.

- The @replies would link to http://twitter.com/replies
- ## Hashtags would like to http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23hashtags

I've found a class for parsing URLs and I'm wondering if this could also be used to parse @replies and #hashtags as well:

```
// http://josephscott.org/archives/2008/11/makeitlink-detecting-urls-in-text-and-making-them-links/    
class MakeItLink {
protected function _link_www( $matches ) {
    $url = $matches[2];
    $url = MakeItLink::cleanURL( $url );
    if( empty( $url ) ) {
        return $matches[0];
    }

    return "{$matches[1]}<a href='{$url}'>{$url}</a>";
}

public function cleanURL( $url ) {
    if( $url == '' ) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = preg_replace( "|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$*'()x80-xff]|i", '', $url );
    $url = str_replace( array( "%0d", "%0a" ), '', $url );
    $url = str_replace( ";//", "://", $url );

    /* If the URL doesn't appear to contain a scheme, we
     * presume it needs http:// appended (unless a relative
     * link starting with / or a php file).
     */
    if(
        strpos( $url, ":" ) === false
        && substr( $url, 0, 1 ) != "/"
        && !preg_match( "|^[a-z0-9-]+?.php|i", $url )
    ) {
        $url = "http://{$url}";
    }

    // Replace ampersans and single quotes
    $url = preg_replace( "|&([^#])(?![a-z]{2,8};)|", "&#038;$1", $url );
    $url = str_replace( "'", "&#039;", $url );

    return $url;
}

public function transform( $text ) {
    $text = " {$text}";

    $text = preg_replace_callback(
        '#(?<=[\s>])(\()?([\w]+?://(?:[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~/\-=?@\[\](+]|[.,;:](?![\s<])|(?(1)\)(?![\s<])|\)))*)#is',
        array( 'MakeItLink', '_link_www' ),
        $text
    );

    $text = preg_replace( '#(<a( [^>]+?>|>))<a [^>]+?>([^>]+?)</a></a>#i', "$1$3</a>", $text );
    $text = trim( $text );

    return $text;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  Are you having trouble with this code?

Comment: Yep, this class only parses links, I'd like to also parse @replies and #hashtags and turn them into links

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think what you're looking to do is essentially what I've included below. You'd add these two statements in `transform` method, just before the return statement.

```
$text = preg_replace('#@(\w+)#', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">$0</a>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/#(\w+)/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$1&src=hash">$0</a>', $text);
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I love how simple this implementation is. Correcto!

Comment: Hi @SoaperGEM, this does not take into account special characters in hashtags, say, it does not work for words like #Prévoyance. Any workaround ?

Answer (score 3):

Twitter [recently released](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/02/introducing-open-source-twitter-text.html) to open source both [java](http://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-java) and [ruby](http://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-rb) ([gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-text)) implementations of the code they use for finding user names, hash tags, lists and urls.

It is very regular expression oriented.